# Deque of Pairs in C++

Tags: c++, deque, std-pair

Every time I call this function, I will get a Segmentation Fault. I found that the pop_front() function did not run as I expected. I tried replacing it with the erase function, but it did not solve the problem. I would like to ask why does it not work and how should I solve it.

```
void front(deque <pair<int64_t, int64_t>> p, int64_t o, int64_t t, int64_t per)
{
    int64_t i=0;
    while(i<per) {
        if(p.front().second > per) {
            i = per;
            p.front().second =- per;
        }
        else {
            i = p.front().second;
            p.pop_front();
        }
    }
    p.push_front(make_pair(t, o+per));
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are trying to access an empty deque. You can check it

Comment: Btw, you should pass `p` by reference, otherwise you get a local copy of the deque and your function won't change anything in the original deque

Comment: `while(i<per && !p.empty())` ?